# How to access sharepoint files which requires username/password?

Tags: excel, sharepoint, vbscript, vba

I tried opening them using `Excel.Workbooks.Open(url)`. However I,m getting the Windows Security authentication prompt.

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro which you can then examine to see how Excel does it?

Comment: Workbooks.Open Filename:= "https://.../.../.../.../Data.xlsx"  this is how it shows on recording